# Does Ubuntu come with a firewall?

Tags: firewall

I'm new to ubuntu, does it come with a firewall installed or will I have to install one, if so which one is best.

Answer (score 0):

Your question looks really broad, however just to mention that "Ubuntu has pre installed firewall and a Set of Rules what so called "IPTABLES".

You can do

> `sudo ufw status`        #this gives you the status if firewall is active or inactive

or

> `sudo ufw enable`   #enables the firewall

or

> `sudo ufw -h #displays all possible options`

To enable the firewall just type  `sudo ufw enable ssh` #this will enable firewall for ssh.

You can add some rules using **iptables** Command

> `sudo iptables -L -n` #will list available rules for IPTABLES such as (INPUT, OUTPUT,NAT,etc.)

Comment: UFW is a separate package, it's description is: *"The Uncomplicated FireWall is a front-end for iptables, to make managing a
Netfilter firewall easier. It provides a command line interface with syntax
similar to OpenBSD's Packet Filter. It is particularly well-suited as a
host-based firewall."* It's supposed to be far easier using ufw to add rules than using iptables directly